# Broken accents in Git files committed by coworker

Tags: git, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I work with another person on the same project. We both use Git on Windows.

When he commits any code file that contain an accent letter (à è ì ò ù) this gets broken once I pull it. Example below:

```
description: "idSoggetto �  un id valido"
```

I checked the remote repository via BitBucket web interface, but it looks like the accents are correct.

Example below

[image]

I am confident then that this is a problem with **me** pulling, I also need to make sure that this does or doesn't happen on the opposite side (he pulling my modifications on accents).

Question is: how can I fix the character encoding during pull? I use SSH for remote repository access

My `.gitattributes` contains

```
* text=auto !eol
/Changelog.txt -text
/README.TEMPLATE.TXT -text
/build.version -text
/build.xml -text svneol=unset#application/xml
/dependencies-ext.xml -text svneol=unset#application/xml
/dependencies.xml -text svneol=unset#application/xml
/phoenix.sh -text
```

Those lines may come from the past (repository ported from Svn, then my project was forked from that Git template repository)

[Add]
Following @kan's comment, I tried to open a file using `vi` (under Git shell). I am 100000000% sure that the file was not touched by Eclipse, otherwise I would get a proposal commit. The result are still broken accents

[image]

Comment: git doesn't change file contents. Most probably you are using different encoding in a program which you use to view the files.

Comment: Interesting. I opened a file with Git bash's `vi`, same problem. I'll update

Comment: Ask your coworker to send his good-looking file to you not using git (e.g. by email or something) and see how it looks for you.

Comment: Before you can try to make your tools do the right thing, you should be able to say what the right thing is. Namely, what is the character encoding of the file, and what is the incorrect character encoding you are using?

Comment: All supposed to be UTF-8 but I'll do a check in Eclipse. How do I find out what character encoding is vi using

Comment: @kan git can change line endings, though I doubt this is the culprit here.

Comment: you can use `git cat-file -p HASH:PATH` to examine file content before git applies the newline transformation to it. You can use the xxd utility which comes with git for windows to see the exact bytes in the file, or pipe the otput of the command above to it